# "Submit" JSP in iFrame

Tags: html, forms, jsp, iframe

I have a dropdown list, where a user's selection determines the inputs to display next.

For example, selecting birds will open a page where a user is asked to enter wingspan, beak type, feather type, or whatever.
Selecting fish will create a completely different page. This is all created dynamically through jsp, getting data from a textfile through Java. (please ignore bad coding)

How do I make this second jsp load in an iFrame on the same page, instead of redirecting to a new page?

I'd (ideally) like to be able to select different options from the dropdown, and see the input form change with each click of the submit button.

The user selects from the dropdown list, and clicks submit, which calls the jsp method / page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" target="frame">
<select name="selection">
  <option value="fish">Fish</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<iframe name="frame"></iframe>
```

In the target give the name of the iframe as target,and the action will get executed in the iframe

Comment: Ah, thank you! Perfect!!
Mind if I ask another?

I would like the user to create his own input form. (all these are used to send data to a Couchbase server)
I am asking a user to select the number of input fields he'd like, then I'll provide him with a page with that number of inputs, where he can choose a name for each, and what type they should all be, etc. So basically, I'm letting the user create his own HTML page without him having to code. This will be a lot of JSP files, and a lot of redirecting / iFrames. I'm chaining JSP files, to communicate with a Java class. Any better ideas?

Comment: I have very little experience in web-coding, and a limited amount of time to get this up and running. I've made a lot of progress so far. I generate most of my code in Java, then return it as a string for jsp to output. This is how I've managed to get data to and from the user. It works, even though I know it's really bad to code this way. But it works really well, except for having to click a lot of buttons to get to the next section.

Comment: but the problem will arise for your backend as you wont know how many fields the user would want and hence you wont be able to set the number of columns in d database.@Flakkenmarsh

Comment: with couchbase I don't need a number of columns, as it uses NoSQL. I just submit the input data as a string, formatted as JSON.

Comment: @Flakkenmarsh did my answer help u,if YES give a tick..and for the new question it would be better you post it,it sounds very interesting...more ppl will be able to help,here it will b oly me..thnk u

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you!

Comment: I've figured something out. Even worse coding, but still effective. I will ask if it starts failing though.